# How to use Spring io Direct channel for passing messages from one queue to other ? Please give a context configuration example

Tags: spring-jms, spring-io

I want to pass message from one queue to other without any processing - how to configure in spring io ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<int:jms-message-driven-channel-adapter channel="foo" ... />

<int:channel id="foo" />

<int:jms-outbound-channel-adapter channel="foo" ... />
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html) for full details.

Comment: thanks Russell a lot ... how to fix the message read count .. I want to stop after 50 message read ?